# Por que cuando subo una pagina a GitHub, solo me le el HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo este el problema siguiente, hice una página la cual en la computadora la puedo ver perfecto pero cuando la subo a GitHub solo me muestra el HTML y no entiendo el por que.

la pagina tiene: -CSS
-JS
-Bootstrap
-jQuery

dejo la pagina completa en el link:
git@github.com:giovanniantonygarcia/VIDRIALUM.COM.git

Answer (score 0):

Entre a tu repositorio, intente ingresar a tu página con la liga que colocaste y no es posible. Creo que estas confundiendo el subir un proyecto a un repositorio en github a usar github como un hosting web.

Te recomiendo seguir [estos pasos](https://pages.github.com/) para que puedas desplegar tu página. En caso que la liga que colocaste sea incorrecta, corrigela.